# Проверить на наличие li в ul

Tags: javascript, html, ul

Я пытаюсь сделать таймер на JS, и сейчас я пытаюсь сделать добавление таймера. Я хочу сделать, чтобы перед добавлением элемента, шла проверка на наличие такой строки в ul. Подскажите, как это сделать.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: if (document.querySelector('ul li'))alert('ul has li')

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли. Мне нужно, чтобы проверялось на наличие ОПРЕДЕЛЁННОЙ строки. например - "10 секунд".

Comment: Добавьте Вашу разметку в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Пример:

```js
function find(id)
{
let el = $('#list').find('li[id="'+id+'"]');
console.log(el);
if($(el).length>0)
{
alert('найдено');
}
else
{
alert('элемента нет');
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
<li id="1">1</li>
<li id="2">2</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" onclick="find(3)" value="Найти элемент с id=3" />
```